# How can I create a Decimal with a large exponent in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3 seems to have some arbitrary limit to Decimal sizes that Python 2 does not. The following code works on Python 2:

```
Decimal('1e+100000000000000000000')
```

But on Python 3 I get:

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

Increasing the precision does not help. Why is this happening? Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: It seems to be related to the precision of your OS.  In python2 you get Decimal('infinity') but python3 doesn't seem to allow 'infinity' in decimal.

Comment: Sorry that I can't help but I have no error with python2 or python3. Could even write a much larger number.

Comment: @gdlmx what are you basing that on? If it's related to the precision of my OS, why does it not happen on Python 2? Also, Decimal('Infinity') does work.

Comment: Actually a `decimal.Overflow` could be expected rather than a `decimal.InvalidOperation`, what is always related to an _operation_. In your example, there is no operation at all.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm I just test different length starting from `1e10` to `1e100000000`, the max length acceptable to python3 is approx. the max integer that can be handle by my cpu. I am not quite sure though. According to the documentation there is a setting 'Emax', which should cause `decimal.Overflow`. Of course Decimal('infinity') works, I just mean python3 doesn't quietly transform a large number to it.

Comment: I am curious to know what `1e+100000000000000000000` is useful for :)

Comment: I am implementing tag #264 in the CBOR specification, which allows for exponents larger than 64 bits. Presumably this might be useful for astronomical calculations or such.

Comment: Even though you can create such decimals in Python 2 (or Python 3 if you disable the `_decimal` C helper module by setting `sys.modules['_decimal'] = None`), any attempt to do anything with the result will give you a `Overflow: above Emax` error.

Comment: Yes, I just discovered this myself. I think I just need to give it up.

Comment: Nope, you can actually work with gigantic decimals in Python 2 (or Python 3 without the C extension) by setting `getcontext().Emax = SOME_REALLY_LARGE_NUMBER`. Of course, the precision is less that 1 with that high an exponent.

Comment: @ppperry No, apparently ssize_t limits the exponent, at least according to the error I get. See the accepted answer for details.

Comment: You are using the C extension. Disabling it (by setting `sys.modules['_decimal'] = None` **before importing the `decimal` module**) will allow tyou to work with arbitrarily large decimals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that `Decimal`s actually *can't* hold arbitrarily long numbers:

```
>>> d = Decimal('10') ** Decimal('100000000000000000000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.Overflow: [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]
```

Indeed, I never heard that arbitrarily long numbers was the point of `Decimal` - just proper rounding and decimals of arbitrary precision. If you want an arbitrarily long number, that's what longs are for, and in Python3 that's just what you've got.

```
>>> d = 10 ** 100000000000000000000
```

(Though it takes a long long while to compute this. My Mac book with I believe a core i5 *still* hasn't finished after a couple of minutes. Heck, even the string 1, followed by all those zeroes, is going to be really *really* big.)

For further kicks and grins, I discovered that you can [configure the overflow value, apparently](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Overflow), though you still can't get such a whopping big number:

```
>>> from decimal import getcontext
>>> getcontext().Emax = 100000000000000000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

Comment: It looks like Python 2 allows me to create such large numbers but refuses to operate on them due to the exponent being above Emax.

Comment: In python 2, it is possible to specify an arbitrarily large `Emax`. The same behavior is True in Python 3 if you set `sys.modules['_decimal'] = None` before importing the `decimal` module.

Comment: @ppperry very interesting. And also sounds like a terrible thing to do ;)